# XMLHttpRequest eval загрузка скрипта и избавление от варнинга

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, интерфейс, eval

Писал в английской версии сайта, после чего он попал сюда, кто не понял вопрос, извините.

Я создаю структуру Javascript напоминающую Ядро-Песочницу и модули (в моем случае со структурой IIFE).
Мне нравится идея подключения скриптов внутри скриптов (как аналогия include или required).
Я подключения script через XMLHttpRequest и eval:

```
var transport = js.getXHTTPTransport(); // my function
    transport.open('GET', js.pathToUrl(path, version), false);
    transport.send(null);
```

Я вижу загруженные скрипты, их можно увидеть во вкладке Network отладчика, но есть предупреждение:

**Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated**

Можете ли вы посоветовать:

1. Нормальный ли это способ подключения скриптов таким путем, так сказать, с учетом современных фреймворков и плагинов (не хочу использовать отдельную библиотеку, на подобии RequireJS) только лишь ради функции подключения? И будет ли это отражаться на скорости загрузки страницы?
   Есть много примеров, но мне так и не понятно, хорошая/нормальная ли это практика такого "теневого" подключения и влияет ли это на страницу. Для меня это удобство подключения необходимых библиотек, именно внутри определенного файла:
   https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/even-faster-web/9780596803773/ch04.html
2. Можно ли избавить от варнинга и существенно ли это? Все таки предупреждение - это предупреждение, не очень камильфо, или лучше подключать скрипты путем той же инъекции тега скрипт на страницу? Последнее, мне как-то не очень нравится.

Спасибо за помощь.

Comment: Перевел, как вы и просили. Если не затурднит, посоветуйте кто-нибудь что-то полезное. Спасибо.

Comment: предупреждение просто говорит, что нужно бы асинхронный запрос спользовать, конкретнее заменить `false` в методе `open` на `true`

Comment: @Grundy Поставив такое и подключая скажем jquery (`js.include('libraries/jquery/jquery-1.11.3.min');`), асинхронно библиотека не отрабатывает. Я так понимаю что все происходит в разное время и что-то грузится раньше другого. Со значением `false` все происходит "по сценарию", но вызывает предупреждение. Правильно ли в данном случае использовать setTimeout?

Comment: правильно, можно просто следующий модуль загружать по событию загрузки зависимости

Comment: а зачем setTimeout?

Comment: а чем не нравится `RequireJS`? если не ошибаюсь подключение скриптов это как раз и есть ее основное предназначение?

Comment: @Grundy Уточню. Вы имеете в виду по загрузке `document ready`, но в этом случае у меня еще нет jquery библиотеки для каких либо проверок. То есть мне нужно каким-то образом увидеть что документ готов и уже после загружать на него инклюд? Я так понимаю что это нужно повесить стандартный обработчик на например body?

Comment: @Grundy Не нравится RequireJS необходимостью ее использовать только ради одной функции. Также она привязывает к своему синтаксису require вызова и зависимостей.

Comment: @Grundy Поделитесь мыслями, повлияет ли как-то такая загрузка на загрузку страницы и лучше ли использовать внедрение динамичного тега подключения скрипта (вроде как ReuqireJS по этому принципу)

Comment: я вообще имел ввиду подход как вот тут: https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/even-faster-web/9780596803773/ch04.html#I_programlisting4_d1e3092 Хотя использование eval мне не очень нравится :-)

Comment: @Grundy Понял, значит вы за динамичное внедрение тега, судя по всему это хорошее решенее. Большое спасибо мысли)

Comment: что за динамическое внедрение?:-)

Comment: @Grundy На что мы оба ссылались `var scriptElem = document.createElement('script');
            document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(scriptElem);

Comment: я вообще там потом якорь дописал :-) https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/even-faster-web/9780596803773/ch04.html#I_programlisting4_d1e3092

Comment: код который идет под картинкой: Figure 4-3. Loading scripts using XHR Eval

Comment: ну и в принципе без разницы на самом деле

Comment: @Grundy Спасибо за ответ. Тему можно закрывать.

Comment: @Grundy Пожалуйста, опубликуйте ваши комментарии в виде ответа.

Comment: немного предупреждения на будущее. у нас тоже было динамическая загрузка js/css. после мажорного обновления back-end реализовали максимально модульную архитектуру, это удобно и гибко. а в результате во front-end для одной страницы по 10 js файлов и 20 css файлов. поэтому перешли на склейку и подключение одним файлом, плюс пара библиотек.

Comment: Согласен, тоже к этому со временем прийдем, но это можно сразу же со стороны backend-а делать с помощью библиотек. На фронте как и вы хотел решить проблему модульности, но в итоге чтобы не создавать дополнительных дыр для вредоносных инъекций через eval, решили все делать через обычный script. На backend-е также проходит выборочное подключение, таким образом на странице нет лишних библиотек. Спасибо за мысли, тоже учту)

Answer (score 1):

Как такового ответа никто не дал и как оказалось, это специфический вопрос, зависящий от вашей необходимости и желания.
Сразу же хочу порекомендовать книгу: [Even Faster Websites](ftp://ftp.micronet-rostov.ru/linux-support/books/programming/[O%60Reilly]%20-%20Even%20Faster%20Websites%20-%20[Souders].pdf).

В ней есть интересная статистика и приписка: Использование eval, потенциально медленнее чем использование Инъекции - динамического создания DOM скрипта (Using eval is potentially slower than using this mechanism). Однако есть еще необходимость узнавать ответ от ready объекта, который сюдя по учебнику срабатывает не везде.

После чего, лично для себя, я решил остановится на подобном создании скриптов и который судя по статистике значительно быстрее аналогов:

```
var scriptElement = document.createElement('script');
    scriptElement.src = 'js/' + moduleName + '.js';
    scriptElement.setAttribute('data-module-name', moduleName);
    scriptElement.addEventListener("load", function(){
        setTimeout(_resolve, 0); // функция добавления в фабрику модулей
    });
    document.body.appendChild(scriptElement);
```

Таким образом, можно подключать в нужном файле, необходимые зависимости:

```
define('core', ['libraries/jquery/jquery-1.11.3.min'], function(jQuery) {
```

создавая некое подобие работы RequireJS. Кому интересно дальнейшее изучение, может обратиться к данному решению (не знаю зачем были предложены некоторые методы использования и как говорится в начале статьи это чисто теоритический подход, оказавшийся весьма практичным):
https://github.com/sunpig/requirejs-from-scratch

Или еще один пример библиотеки, который я не использовал, но преследующий похожую цель: www.getcodesamples.com/src/46553AE5/F5352C78

Надеюсь, кому-то это пригодится и в какой-то степени отвечает на вопрос.